# Why does a CustomTrackingRecord with a TraceLevel set always appear in AppFabric Dasboard as 'Information'?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

AppFabric v1.1 / WF4

When I create a CustomTrackingRecord within a CodeActivity specifying both text and Tracelevel I'm getting the TraceLevel in AppFabric Dashboard always displaying as 'Information', could someone explain to me why this is?

```
    // Text Argument
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

    // TraceLevel Property
    public TraceLevel TraceLevel { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tracks the text message contained in the Text argument.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The execution context under which the activity executes.</param>
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Obtain the runtime value of the Text and TraceLevel input arguments
        string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);

        // Create and initialize a custom tracking record 
        CustomTrackingRecord record = new CustomTrackingRecord(text, this.TraceLevel);

        // Sends the specified custom tracking record to any registered tracking providers
        context.Track(record);
    }
```

BTW I've checked the [ASStagingTable] and [ASWfEventsTable] tables and TraceLevelId is always 4 for my CustomTrackingRecords.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an InArgument on TrackLevel

```
// TraceLevel Property
public InArgument<TraceLevel> TraceLevel { get; set; }
```

Then use the context to get the value at runtime of the workflow

```
// Create and initialize a custom tracking record 
CustomTrackingRecord record = new CustomTrackingRecord(text, context.GetValue(this.TraceLevel));
```